# Postgresql - Count number of instances of substring in results of ILIKE query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like this, that returns rows of text that match the given query:

```
SELECT content 
FROM messages 
  WHERE created_at >= '2021-07-24T20:17:18.141Z'
        AND created_at <= '2021-07-31T20:11:20.542Z'
        AND content ILIKE '%Search Term%';
```

Right now, if I just count the rows, it just returns the number of messages with that search term. However, I'd like to count the number of *Instances* of the search term, rather than the number of *Rows that contain* the search term.

I thought of making a stored function that looped through the results of the above function and counted the instances. But it ended up being insanely slow. I’m okay with it being pretty slow, but is there a solution to this that either runs slightly faster or doesn’t require a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN content ILIKE '%Search Term%' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END
  )
FROM
  messages 
WHERE
  created_at >= '2021-07-24T20:17:18.141Z' AND
  created_at <= '2021-07-31T20:11:20.542Z';
```

Comment: Or a bit simpler: `count(*) filter (where content ilike '...')`

Comment: Thanks! This actually works a lot faster than the accepted answer, down from 200ms to 50ms on a real query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, good point. I didn't know PostgreSQL was ISO compliant in this regard.

Comment: @thecoolwinter, this is because your query has become [sargable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_matches()`:

```
select count(*)
from messages m cross join lateral
     regexp_matches(m.content, $search_string, 'g')
```

Note:  This assumes that `$search_string` doesn't contain regular expression special characters.

If you want the count on each row, you can use:

```
select m.*,
       (select count(*) 
        from regexp_matches(m.content, $search_string, 'g')
       ) as num_matches
from messages m;
```

Comment: This looks good, how would I combine this with the above query? I'm really newb to SQL, so sorry for dumb question. And what would a regular expression special character be? Right now I'm wrapping my search in `%{Term}%` to get any instances of the search, should I remove the `%`s from the query?

Comment: @thecoolwinter . . . You are fine with just letters, numbers, and spaces.

Comment: Perfect  thank you, marked as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Now I understood your question properly. You can use `regexp_matches()` in substring to get what you want.

```
select content,(SELECT count(*) FROM regexp_matches(content, 'Search Term', 'g')) search_count 
FROM messages 
  WHERE created_at >= '2021-07-24T20:17:18.141Z'
        AND created_at <= '2021-07-31T20:11:20.542Z'
        AND content ILIKE '%Search Term%';
```

** The 'g' flag repeats multiple matches on a string.

Comment: Not quite, this still counts the number of rows returned by the query, but say one of the rows has `Search Term, Search Term` I'd like that row to be counted as 2 since it has two of the search term